# cannot install plyr package in R

Tags: r, installation, plyr

I am having difficulties with installing plyr in R. The very same problem has been posted in various forums before, but none of the suggested solutions there worked for. To summarize, I am trying to install it using this command (output below):

```
install.packages("plyr") 

Installing package into ‘/home/m2108/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘plyr’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

Then I have tried to manually download the package from the cran server and use this command instead and receive the same error:

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/home/m2108/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

ERROR: this R is version 3.0.2, package 'plyr' requires R >= 3.1.0
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/home/m2108/Downloads/plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have also switched repositores (or added others) with this command:
setRepositories()

Does anyone have an idea, what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I have just tried to install the 'doBy' package and received the same error message. So apparently it is not a 'plyr' specific problem.

Comment: Short Update: When I tried to install 'doBy' from the command line R, instead of R Studio, it suddenly worked (i.e. it asked me to select a CRAN mirror and the downloaded it).

Comment: But for 'plyr' I still get the same error message.

Comment: Like I said, I tried the suggested solution from the other question (try to downloadit manually from CRAN and set repos=NULL) but I receive the same error message.